# APC UPS: Warning Old Configuration File Found

Tags: ups

I have a APC UPS hooked up to a computer running Unbuntu 20.04.3. I am trying to test the UPS to make sure it works properly but when I run the commands `apctest` and `apcupsd`, I get the below returns. Do I need to make some sort of update or was it configured improperly?

**`apctest` Return**

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

2021-11-07 17:22:40 Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

apctest 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

Checking configuration ...

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

: Warning: old configuration file found.

: Expected: "## apcupsd.conf v1.1 ##"

: Found: "

"

: Please check new file format and

: modify accordingly the first line

: of config file.

: Processing config file anyway.

sharenet.type = Network & ShareUPS Disabled

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

cable.type = USB Cable

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

mode.type = USB UPS Driver

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

apctest FATAL ERROR in apctest.c at line 311

Unable to create UPS lock file.

If apcupsd or apctest is already running,

please stop it and run this program again.

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

apctest error termination completed

Could not create apctest.output: Permission denied

**`apcupsd` Return**

apcupsd: Warning: old configuration file found.

apcupsd: Expected: "## apcupsd.conf v1.1 ##"

apcupsd: Found: "

"

apcupsd: Please check new file format and

apcupsd: modify accordingly the first line

apcupsd: of config file.

apcupsd: Processing config file anyway.

Comment: Did you stop apcupsd? Did you run apctest with sudo?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks! Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

- Check the settings of UPSCABLE and UPSTYPE in /etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf, and they should probably be "usb". Check that DEVICE is commented out, like "#DEVICE /dev/ttyS0"
- Check the setting in /etc/default/apcupsd, and it should be "ISCONFIGURED=yes"
- Uninstall `apcupsd` with `sudo apt-get purge apcupsd`
- Confirm that all files in /etc/apcupsd are gone
- Reinstall `apcupsd` with `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install apcupsd`
- Configure /etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf and /etc/default/apcupsd using the settings that you checked earlier
- `sudo systemctl stop apcupsd`
- `sudo apctest`
- `sudo systemctl start apcupsd`
- `systemctl status apcupsd`
- `grep -i apcupsd /var/log/syslog`

Comment: is this a command: `/etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf`?

Comment: @Barnett No, it's one of two configuration files that you have to edit after installing apcupsd.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after cleaning up the example config file by removing all comments.  This error gives the answer:

```
apcupsd: Expected: "## apcupsd.conf v1.1 ##"
```

So I literally added this line to the top of /etc/apcupsd/apcupsd.conf

```
## apcupsd.conf v1.1 ##
```

now apctest and apcaccess fire off without warning.